# How do I add custom GPG key to Ubuntu/Debian installer?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gpg, debian-installer

I'm trying to setup custom Ubuntu install CD using instructions on http://beezari.livejournal.com/191717.html
I've added my GPG key to ubuntu-keyring and signed Release file with it (resulting in Release.gpg signature file)
But during installation I get

```
gpgv: Can't check signature public key not found
```

It looks like to install new ubuntu-keyring with my key I need to have it already installed (in debian-installer maybe?).
I can get around with `debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated=false` but it seems to be quite bad practice.

**Update**

This installer CD is supposed to be used for unattended installation using PXE

Comment: For the installer itself, .udeb (not .deb) packages are relevant. Have you considered this?

Comment: it was compiled alongside with deb package and copied to corresponding pool/main subfolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem has to do with the fact that I use initrd from netboot. And that initrd has `/usr/share/keyrings` in it.

I've updated ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg there and problem with signature seems to be solved.

Though ubuntu-installer can not find my packages added to extras.

Comment: I rebuilt archive keyring package and used early_command instead of rebuilding initrd:

`d-i preseed/early_command string wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/archive.gpg http://${paella_server_ip}/debrepos/paella.bin.gpg`