# Linux Run a Script to configure first Boot and Install

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

From the manufacturer we receive devices that have the Ubuntu 16.04 os installed on them. They are not set up, they come exactly as you would expect a consumer version to look. It asks for your region, keyboard layout, wifi connection info, etc.

How would I go about overriding this and just have a script run to set all this up preferably from a usb that would be plugged in before first boot from the manufacturer?

**Edit**

It appears as if there is more information that I can provide. These devices are only pc sticks. they do not have an ethernet port. They do have a usb port.

Comment: You could look into an imaging solution using something like [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/). Create the perfect set up of whatever operating system you want and clone it to however many machines or use pxe boot to install an operating system onto many computers at once.

Comment: @kemotep That qualifies as an answer to me...  Ping me after you've posted one and I'll come back and upvote!

Comment: @Fabby, I submitted an answer. Feel free to make any edits if you think the post could be improved.

Comment: @kemotep I provided more detail. I see now how this was more pertinent.

Comment: @christopherclark, I am not familiar with what a PC stick is. When you say they have a USB port can you plug a flash drive into them? I can update my post to have more relevant instructions towards USB cloning. You issue is going to be that to do many at once you will need many flash drives and will have to still complete some steps manually for each individual computer. Ask yourself, is it worth it to learn how to image the computers in this manner or will it be faster to complete the process you are originally doing?

Comment: @kemotep usb boot is enabled by default. So I should be able to clone an os I need, that is already preconfigured, plug in the usb into the devices, and have it auto set up and configure everything. P.S. A PC stick is a computer contained in a small device that has an hdmi out so you can plug it into any monitor.

Comment: @christopherclark I have updated my answer. Please comment under it if you have additional issues or concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue at Hand

The scope of your issue is that you receive computers from the manufacturer with an Operating System that is not set up yet. You wish to speed up the process of setting up these computers to reduce the time in which it takes to deploy them to an end user. You would also like to automate this task as you most likely have many machines in which you need to do this for.

I highly suggest that you consider acquiring the infrastructure for an imaging system to mass deploy a custom ready-to-go Operating System to your machines via the network. [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) is a free and open source solution that can be used as a live boot or server to back up, clone, and image devices. They even have a [step-by-step guide](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/11_lite_server) on how to create an imaging server to do mass deployments. This option will involve you purchasing alternative devices such as more traditional desktops, laptops, or  other kinds of devices which do have Ethernet ports as well as additional networking devices such as switches and routers. At this time, as far as I know, only Apple has a proprietary solution for Wireless Network Booting. But to work with what you have here is a possible solution.

## Possible Solution

Since you clarified that your issue involves PC sticks that lack Ethernet ports to connect many devices over the network to your imaging server you can always create several flash drives with Clonezilla and a copy of the "golden image" to simply plug in, boot up, and image the computer. [Here is a link to the Clonezilla Documentation on doing this](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php).

To do this you will need flash drives formatted with the Clonezilla live boot and a data partition that is large enough for your "Golden Image" that you will use Clonezilla to create. If you have a Windows Computer, [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) is an excellent tool to easily create the Clonezilla Live USB with a Data partition. However standard `dd if=/Path/To/Clonezilla.iso of=/dev/sdX` where X is your flash drive and you then format a data partition for the remaining space afterwards works as well. Afterwards, clone your "Golden Image" following [this guide](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) and then deploy your image to the next machine following [this guide](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone)

## Conclusion

Again, I highly suggest an imaging solution. Everywhere that I have worked has used some kind of imaging solution to be able to mass deploy new computers. You can create images based on different departments or kinds of users so it has the exact software needed and is ready to go for them. The specifics of what you need are up to you alone so take some time and try to research a solution that works best for you.

I am including the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) page on how to create a custom Ubuntu installation if you are set on using Ubuntu. It is a long process but you only need to do it once to be able to replicate it to many machines. People have reported issues with gpg keys so i am also including a [link to a post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97520/how-do-i-add-custom-gpg-key-to-ubuntu-debian-installer) that could fix that specific issue.

As always, if there are any misconceptions or issues with my answer please comment, I appreciate corrections to my mistakes. Best of Luck!

Comment: Upvoted as promised!

Comment: @kemotep I can't even figure out what option to choose. on the help docs. There are like 80 of them.

Comment: If I'm understanding this right. I do Step 2 USB Part here. https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php. Then I follow the steps for `One image to multiple disks` My disks being the USB flash Drive. Found here. https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php. Then once I do those `11` steps I'll have several usb's that will actually INSTALL the cloned copy of OS including all repository installs, all environment variables, all user settings to the target device?

Comment: @kemotep I'm sorry could you confirm the above steps are correct?

Comment: @christopherclark, okay so from what I understand is that you will create your "golden image" operating system, so install all of the applications, configure settings, set up drivers, etc. Then, create a Clonezilla Live Boot flash drive by downloading the iso and writing it to a flash drive. Make sure it is a large enough flash drive to store both the live boot and a data partition that will be large enough to hold your golden image. At this point follow [this guide](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php) step by step it will guide you.

Comment: @christopherclark, You can then move on to the second section, "Restore Disk Image" to be able to restore your golden image to a new disk. Boot the flash drive off of the machine you wish to restore to and follow the steps. The "One image to multiple disks" looks like it would be great only if you could connect all of the hard drives of all of the computers you are creating to one machine. However,I have never done that. I use a server to pxe boot all of the machines I want to image over the network or I have simply used the live boot to do back ups. I am not familiar with the other process.